# How to find out the order of sheets created?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

This is important because the order of execution is based on the first created sheet to the last created sheet which ordinarily is not an issue but is an issue for circular references. Obviously I can put something in the name to remind me but there seems to be no pattern to the gid number and therefore have no way to know for already created spreadsheets with custom sheet names without painfully testing circular reference formulas.

This is not part of my question but here is an example to demonstrate why this is so important:

```
Step 1) File->Spreadsheet Settings->Calculation->Iterative Calculation(On)->Max number of iterations(1)
Step 2) Set up the following test formulas
Cell A1 =A1+1
Cell B1 =A1
Cell A2 =B2
Cell B2 = B2+1
```

You will notice that even though they formulas should have the same results they do not due to the execution order, now this example is just of a single sheet but invisibly the original sheet creation order is the order of execution when formulas reference other sheets.

Comment: Can I ask you about your situation? 1. About "the order of sheets created", when there is one Spreadsheet, does this mean the order of sheets which were created in the Spreadsheet? 2. In your situation, are the sheets renamed, moved and deleted? 3. How do you want to achieve your goal? For example, it's manual operation and/or use of script.

Comment: @Tanaike I have resolved my issue by just creating new sheets so I know what order they were made in but I asked this question anyway in case I ever want to make use complex circular functions. I will add an example in my question to demonstrate why this is important.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about it. This is due to my poor understanding. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike If you go to Google Sheets settings as I showed in step 1 and turn on iterative calculations with 1 iteration when you enter the formulas I showed you can see that they do not return the same results even though they are identical formulas simply because of the position in the spreadsheet, you can change the random numbers by pressing the delete key.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I couldn't understand about the relationship between "the order of sheets created" and the result of calculation. I might misunderstand about "the order of sheets created".

Answer (score 1):

The fastest solution that satisfies your request is to use the [getSheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) method to obtain an array where every sheet appears in the same order that Sheet shows in the user interface. Keep an eye on them, because if you move one sheet around in the user interface the array won't reflect the true order of creation.

Another approach, more precise than the former one, is to use the [properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties) class to save a [timestamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) every time that a sheet is created. You can manage that with the [setProperty](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties.html#setpropertykey,-value) and [getProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties.html#getproperties) methods.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I'm surprised there is not already an accessible order property since the order of creation is the order of execution. Too bad the getSheets method does not return the creation order as I always seem to switch around the order of my sheets.

Comment: Hi there @CodeCamper! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/589350) by clicking the checkmark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.